# How to create a centerline from polygon in Arcgis 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

In Network Analyst, I want to create a center line from a road polygon layer of an area for shortest path creation. How do I do this in ArcGIS 10?

Comment: Good catch. I suggest you use flag the post (as a duplicate) for moderator attention so it can be appropriately dealt with :)

Comment: You can use feature to polygon to generate dual lines of the polygon, and then in cartography Tools - Generalization you can use Collapse dual lines to centerline

Answer (score 8):

check out [ET GeoWizards](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/createCenterlines.htm) for ArcGIS. it has some features for finding center lines.

[image: centers]
[image: centers]

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Don't you have to purchase it for this tool? It doesn't seem that ET GeoWizards provides this for free...

Answer (score 5):

If you have the ArcInfo licence you can use [Collapse dual lines to centreline](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Collapse_Dual_Lines_To_Centerline/00700000000t000000/) tool.  This is in the Cartography Toolbox.

Alternatively, if you have Data Interoperability Suite, then you will have FME.  There is also a tool in FME to get centerlines from polygons.

If you don't have ArcInfo licence or FME, go with Aragon's suggestion.